# Save Mapbox static api response to png file with node sdk js

Tags: node.js, png, mapbox, fs

The png file created with the following code using mapbox-sdk-js is unreadable, yet the response headers display content "image/png" and status code is 200. This is not a problem with my token or else, if I use curl with the same parameters I get a proper PNG file (and a nice map).

Could you help me to save the response to a file ? Thanks !

```
const mbxStatic = require('@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/static')
const fs = require('fs')

// Get config
const MAPBOX_TOKEN = process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN

const staticClient = mbxStatic({ accessToken: MAPBOX_TOKEN })

staticClient
  .getStaticImage({
    ownerId: 'mapbox',
    styleId: 'streets-v10',
    width: 200,
    height: 300,
    position: {
      coordinates: [-77, 38],
      zoom: 5
    }
  })
  .send()
  .then(response => {
    const image = response.body
    console.log(response.headers)
    fs.writeFileSync("./map.png", image, 'binary')
  }).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i had the same Problem as you.
My Solution was adding a pump function and saving the result with a createWriteStream function.

Also i didn't use the staticClient but the link from the static playground of mapBox.

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const request =require('request');  
const fs = require('fs');


await pump(request(url), fs.createWriteStream('./map.png', {encoding: 'base64'}));
```

But I guess you can also save the response of the staticClient if you replace the request call. Didn't try it though.